# How to catch errors when having multiple database operations in a @Transactional method in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, error-handling, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I have a service method that is @Transactional.

In this service method, multiple JPA operations happen.

```
  @Transactional
  public Foo fooOperations(String fooId, Foo foo) {

    List<Error> errors = new ArrayList<>();

    updateFoo(fooId, foo).ifPresent(errors::add);

    createNewFoo(foo).ifPresent(errors::add);

    deleteOldFoo(fooId).ifPresent(errors::add);
 
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      throw new CustomException(
          "Foo failed", errors); 
    }

    return getFooById(fooId);
  }
```

Each method is wrapped in a try-catch, and an error is returned in catch block.

However, if there are database errors, nothing is thrown since they are not executed until the end of the method.

So even when the operations have failed, I still get Foo By Id returned.

Is it possible to get all errors back and also keep the method transactional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using saveAndFlush instead of save().

Flush executes the statements immediately.